# Executing stored procedures via OPENDATASOURCE throws error "The OLE DB provider "SQLCLI" has not been registered"

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I was trying to use OPENDATASOURCE to insert some records into a remote SQL Server database and execute a stored procedure afterwards. The following insert statement works very well:

```
INSERT OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI','Server=MyServer;Database=TestDB;User Id=sa;Password=*****;').TestDB.dbo.MyTable
                (Col1,
                Col2,
                Col3)
            SELECT Col1,
                Col2,
                Col3
            FROM AnotherTable
```

However, when I was executing the following stored procedure

```
EXEC OPENDATASOURCE('SQLCLI','Server=MyServer;Database=TestDB;User Id=sa;Password=*****;').TestDB.dbo.MyStoredProcedure
```

I've got this error:

> Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
>   The OLE DB provider "SQLCLI" has not been registered.

The local SQL Server is 2008 R2 64 bit and the remote one is SQL Server 2012. Does anyone know what the problem was? I am desperate for a solution.

Any comments are much appreciated.

Comment: Your first statement uses `SQLNCLI`. Your second one uses `SQLCLI`. Change the second one to use `SQLNCLI`

Comment: Hi Nick, well spotted! I've spent the whole evening without joy! It works now. Thank you very much.